# angular ui modalinstance does not close when outside of dialog is clicked

Tags: angularjs

My code is as shown below:

```
var itemDetails = item;
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true,
                    templateUrl: 'template/itemDetailsPopup.html',
                    controller: 'itemDetailController',
                    resolve: {
                        itemDetails: function() {
                            return itemDetails;
                        }
                    }

                });
```

Through this method, I am successfully able to open the dialog, but the problem when I touch outside the dialog it should close it, but unfortunately it is not happening .
how to enable that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal):

> backdrop (Type: boolean|string, Default: true) - Controls presence of
>   a backdrop. Allowed values: true (default), false (no backdrop),
>   'static' (disables modal closing by click on the backdrop).

So basically, by using the configuration option `backdrop: 'static'` you show the backdrop, but disables closing the modal using the backdrop.

What you want instead is `backdrop: true`.

Comment: I tried using `backdrop:true`, but it is not closed when I touch other part of the screen.

Comment: Can you provide a plunker or similar showing the issue?